# How to add external/thirdparty node modules in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, circular-dependency, nestjs

I am new to `Nodejs`. I am building an application using `Nestjs Version 5`. I need to use some `node_modules` like,

[htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2)
or
[dom-serialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-serialize)

within my application. How can I import those modules and use it in my application.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `Instalation`/`Usage` in the link you added for htmlparser2? Have you tried running `npm install htmlparser2` like it says there? https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2

Comment: Also, please add any steps you have tried and you got stuck on

Comment: Hi @VladTopala,

I installed this module as dev dependency and imported it in my module like this,

import { htmlparser } from 'htmlparser2';

Then I am stuck. How to use it in my service.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: @Lasar Have you tried the code from the `Usage` section?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
import * as zl from 'zlib'
```

Import whatever module you need and "name it" whatever you want in your code, in my example I name it "zl" but i could name it "Sarah" =)